# Plone Upgrade 5.0 -> 5.0.2 fails AttributeError

Tags: plone

I get following AttributeError on migration

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nscgraf/Projects/.buildout/eggs/Products.CMFPlone-5.0.2-py2.7.egg/Products/CMFPlone/MigrationTool.py", line 268, in upgrade
    step['step'].doStep(setup)
  File "/Users/nscgraf/Projects/.buildout/eggs/Products.GenericSetup-1.8.1-py2.7.egg/Products/GenericSetup/upgrade.py", line 166, in doStep
    self.handler(tool)
  File "/Users/nscgraf/Projects/.buildout/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.3.20-py2.7.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v50/final.py", line 83, in to501
    refresh_getIcon_catalog_metadata(context)
  File "/Users/nscgraf/Projects/.buildout/eggs/plone.app.upgrade-1.3.20-py2.7.egg/plone/app/upgrade/v50/final.py", line 72, in refresh_getIcon_catalog_metadata
    new_value = bool(getattr(obj.aq_base, 'image', False))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'aq_base'
```

Upgrade steps:
- 4.3.4.1
- 4.3.9
- 5.0.2 (fails)

On 4.3.9 I uninstalled all "bad/old/useless products" jQuery-integration, jquery-tools...
On every step, I reinstalled all newer Products

I am thankful for hints and ideas..

*(edit, submitted to early)*

Comment: The error message indicates, that the obj is actually a list in your case. Could be a problem with your catalog. I don't have experience upgrading to Plone 5, but I would do aclear & rebuild if the catalog, before you upgrade to a newer Plone version.

Comment: Sorry, updating portal_catalog doesn't work

Comment: Please note @Mathias was talking about performing a clean and rebuild, be sure to have performed this instead of a simple "update".

Comment: Yep very important "Clear & Rebuild" not just an update. Further offering a bounty will not provide you an answer to your question. IMHO you need to debug this issue yourself, since no one else faced the same issue before. This also means for example that you got an issue with a installed addon. Wrap `try: ... except: import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` around the failing line of code, then you will probably see whats the problem.

Comment: Problem found: it comes a list of objects instead an objects, this fails.... I didnt saw that earlier, sorry

Comment: What solved your case, a catalog-rebuild? Was the reason a non-existing obj with a leftover-catalog-entry? 
If that's the case, it might be a bug, if `_unrestrictedGetObject` returns an empty list instead of `None`.

Comment: I made an if-condition, ```if isinstance([], list)```, then make an for-loop